# sum of digits at odd and even places of a string

Tags: c++

The output for the variable sum_e is negative which isn't what I expect it to be.

I have simply added the values at even and odd places and stored them in two variables. I checked for solutions and found ones with digit extraction from a number. None of them had a string input.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    int sum_e=0,sum_o=0;

    int l=s.length();

    for(int i=0;i<=l;i=i+2){
        sum_o+=(s[i]-'0');
    }
    for(int j=1;j<=l;j=j+2){
        sum_e+=(s[j]-'0');
    }
    cout<<sum_o<<endl<<sum_e;
    return 0;
}
```

I subtracted '0' from the string index to convert it into int. One of the variables shows the right output and the other shows a negative one.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<=l;i=i+2){`  and `for(int j=1;j<=l;j=j+2){` looks like an off by 1 error. Remember that `s[s.length()]` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loops run one time longer than the length of the array, so when `i = l`, `s[i]` will get an undefined/garbage value from memory. Use `i < l` and `j < l` rather than `i <= l` and `j <= l`, since the index in C++ begins at zero.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    int sum_e = 0, sum_o = 0;

    int l = s.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < l; i = i + 2){
        sum_o += (s[i] - '0');
    }
    for(int j = 1; j < l; j = j + 2){
        sum_e += (s[j] - '0');
    }

    cout << sum_o << endl << sum_e;

    return 0;
}
```

To improve your code, use one for loop instead of two.

```
for(int i = 0; i < l; i++){
    // Check if even (i%2 returns the remainder of i/2, so here i%2==1 means even)
    if(i%2 == 1){
        sum_e += (s[i] - '0');
    }else{
        sum_o += (s[i] - '0');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array indexing in C++ starts from 0. You store the `length` of string as `l`, so elements of your string lies from `s[0]` to `s[l-1]`. At `s[l]` some garbage value is present which gets added to one of your variables, hence producing undesired results.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    int sum_e=0,sum_o=0;

    int l=s.length();

    for(int i=0;i<l;i=i+2){ // use <
        sum_o+=(s[i]-'0');
    }
    for(int j=1;j<l;j=j+2){ // use <
        sum_e+=(s[j]-'0');
    }

    cout<<sum_o<<endl<<sum_e;

    return 0;
}
```

You can also do your odd and even position sum using a single loop. Your code size will reduce and look better

```
for(int i=0;i<l;i=i+2){ 
        if(i%2==0)// even index means odd position numbers
             sum_o+=(s[i]-'0');
        else
              sum_e+=(s[j]-'0');
    }
```